# Differentiability proof for an interval close to a point

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

$f$ and $g$ are differentiable with $fg'-f'g=0$. Prove if $f(a)=0, g(a)\neq 0$ then $f(x)=0$ $\forall x$ in an interval around $a$.

I think I am very close to solving this, but I am missing the last step.

Let $h=\frac{f}{g}$. Then $h'=\frac{gf'-fg'}{g^2} = 0$ $\Rightarrow $$\frac{f}{g}$ is constant, i.e. $\frac{f}{g}=c\in \mathbb{R}$ for $ (a-\varepsilon, a+\varepsilon)$. Also note that $f=cg$. I think I need to assume towards a contradiction that $f(x)\neq 0$ nearby $a$, but I am likely mistaken. Can anyone help finish the proof?

Answer (score 0):

Starting with what you got, we see that $h(a)=0$ since $f(a)=0$ and $g(a)\neq 0$. Therefore $h\equiv 0$ everywhere it is defined. Since $g$ is continuous, $g(x)\neq 0$ in a neighbourhood of $a$. Therefore $h$ is defined in a neighbourhood of $a$, so $h(x)=0$ in a neighbourhood of $a$, so $f(x)=0$ in a neighbourhood of $a$.